# need to check this col-md(col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4) clarification

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I need 3*3 service box for my website with responsive.But alignment is not proper.each box in 1st row differs in 2nd row and last box is moving to 4th row.so need code for 3*3 box type.

```
       <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="serviceBox_2">
                        <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
                        <h3>Broadband Services</h3>
                        <p>Integer ultrices scelerisque nulla fringilla. 
      Praesent leo massa, ullamcorper venenatis tempor.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="serviceBox_2">
                        <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
                        <h3>Dedicated Leased Line</h3>
                        <p>Integer ultrices scelerisque nulla fringilla. 
     Praesent leo massa, ullamcorper venenatis tempor.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="serviceBox_2">
                        <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>
                        <h3>Dark Fibre</h3>
                        <p>Integer ultrices scelerisque nulla fringilla. 
       Praesent leo massa, ullamcorper venenatis tempor.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="serviceBox_2">
                        <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>
                        <h3>CCTV Installation</h3>
                        <p>Integer ultrices scelerisque nulla fringilla. 
     Praesent leo massa, ullamcorper venenatis tempor.</p>
                    </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12">

                    <div class="serviceBox_2">
                        <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>
                        <h3>CCTV Installation</h3>
                        <p>Integer ultrices scelerisque nulla fringilla. 
     Praesent leo massa, ullamcorper venenatis tempor.</p>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the second to last div incorrectly, making the last div a child of it. Also, Bootstrap provides a [`row` class](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#how-it-works) which can be helpful when making just that, rows.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="serviceBox_2">
                <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
                <h3>Broadband Services</h3>
                <p>Integer ultrices scelerisque nulla fringilla. Praesent leo massa, ullamcorper venenatis tempor.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="serviceBox_2">
                <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
                <h3>Dedicated Leased Line</h3>
                <p>Integer ultrices scelerisque nulla fringilla. Praesent leo massa, ullamcorper venenatis tempor.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="serviceBox_2">
                <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>
                <h3>Dark Fibre</h3>
                <p>Integer ultrices scelerisque nulla fringilla. Praesent leo massa, ullamcorper venenatis tempor.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="serviceBox_2">
                <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>
                <h3>CCTV Installation</h3>
                <p>Integer ultrices scelerisque nulla fringilla. Praesent leo massa, ullamcorper venenatis tempor.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-12 col-xs-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="serviceBox_2">
                <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>
                <h3>CCTV Installation</h3>
                <p>Integer ultrices scelerisque nulla fringilla. Praesent leo massa, ullamcorper venenatis tempor.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add row for every 12 columns.

Also if you want to use sm,md and lg with same values then you just have to use sm.

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="serviceBox_2">
          <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
          <h3>Broadband Services</h3>
          <p>Integer ultrices scelerisque nulla fringilla. Praesent leo massa, ullamcorper venenatis tempor.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 ">
        <div class="serviceBox_2">
          <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>
          <h3>Dedicated Leased Line</h3>
          <p>Integer ultrices scelerisque nulla fringilla. Praesent leo massa, ullamcorper venenatis tempor.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="serviceBox_2">
          <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>
          <h3>Dark Fibre</h3>
          <p>Integer ultrices scelerisque nulla fringilla. Praesent leo massa, ullamcorper venenatis tempor.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="serviceBox_2">
          <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>
          <h3>CCTV Installation</h3>
          <p>Integer ultrices scelerisque nulla fringilla. Praesent leo massa, ullamcorper venenatis tempor.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">

        <div class="serviceBox_2">
          <i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>
          <h3>CCTV Installation</h3>
          <p>Integer ultrices scelerisque nulla fringilla. Praesent leo massa, ullamcorper venenatis tempor.</p>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
```